# How to create a custom handler in view?

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to alter a field's argument handler. But It is showing me `broken/missing` handler in view's argument. I have tried it in following ways :

I am adding the following two code block in `hook_field_views_data_alter` where :

```
$table_name = node__field_test;
$field_col = field_test_value;
```

I want to change handler for a field.

First method by reviewing [time spent](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_spent) module's code :

```
$data[$table_name][$field_col]['argument']['id'] = 'MyClassName';
```

I didn't understand the concept of `id` above and how it will recognise the class of my module?

Second method as in D7 :

```
$data[$table_name][$field_col]['argument']['handler'] = 'MyClassName'; // Second
```

How It works in D8?

Comment: Can you give more of your custom code? For example I have no idea where you are putting these lines of code and what you are intending to do. I'm not going to go digging through to code of some module you have linked to try to work out what you might be talking about.

Comment: @rooby I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is a plugin ID. You either need to define your own views argument plugin and change the id to that or alter the plugin definition and replace the class there.

The first will just update a specific field, the second would replace the plugin everywhere where it is used.

Comment: How the handler will knows about the id. I mean how id works? I am changing the handler of a field using `hook_views_data_alter`.

Comment: There was an issue in notation.